# How to Install Packages for manually added magento2 extension using composer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a magento2 extension, In that composer.json requires extra packages other than the default magento2 packages. How to Install those packages.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Guzzle

The recommended way to install Guzzle is through Composer.

## Install Composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Next, run the Composer command to install the latest stable version of Guzzle:

```
php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

After installing, you need to require Composer's autoloader:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

You can then later update Guzzle using composer:

```
php composer.phar update
```

For more details refer: https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle

Answer (score 4):

Please run the following commands from you Magento Root installation directory.

Step 1:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Step 2:

```
composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Step 3:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Step 4:

```
composer.phar update
```